# Wordpress Advanced Search - Remember what was picked

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm creating a Wordpress Advanced form where on the home page the user has 3 fields to select from, then they hit submit and it goes to another page.

However when it gets to that page it shows the results but the same fields on that page don't remember what was selected.

Is there a way to achieve this, so it remembers and continues to remember until they leave that page?

I've been researching it but not even sure what to search for?...

**EDIT**

Been asked to add my code to help explain it;

```
<form method="post" class="form_search" action="<?php bloginfo('url');?>/job-search/" >
<label>
    Job Title/Keywords
    <input type="text" name="s" class="search_job_title" placeholder="e.g. Truck Driver">
</label>
<label>
    Sector
    <select name="job-sector">
        <option disabled selected value> -- select an option -- </option>
        <?php 
            $terms = get_terms( 'job-sector' );
            if ( ! empty( $terms ) && ! is_wp_error( $terms ) ){                                 
                foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
                    echo '<option>' . $term->name . '</option>';
                }                                   
            }
            ?>
    </select>
</label>
<label>
    Location
    <input type="text" name="job-location" class="search_job_location" placeholder="e.g. Manchester">
</label>
<label>
    <input type="submit" class="search_submit" value="Search">
    <!-- <input type="hidden" name="post_type" value="jobs-board"> -->
</label>
</form>
```

Comment: It's difficult to help with the information that you've given. How exactly are you creating this advanced form? Show us the PHP/markup used.

Comment: Hi George, I've added my code

Answer (score 0):

You need to add POST variables to the form:

```
<form method="post" class="form_search" action="<?php bloginfo('url');?>/job-search/" >
<label>
    Job Title/Keywords
    <input type="text" name="s" class="search_job_title" placeholder="e.g. Truck Driver" value="<?php echo isset($_POST["s"])?esc_attr($_POST["s"]):'';?>" >
</label>
<label>
    Sector
    <select name="job-sector">
        <option disabled selected value> -- select an option -- </option>
        <?php 
            $terms = get_terms( 'job-sector' );
            if ( ! empty( $terms ) && ! is_wp_error( $terms ) ){                                 
                foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
                    echo '<option value="' . $term->name . '" 
                    '.(isset($_POST["job-sector"]) and urldecode($_POST["job-sector"])==$term->name)?'selected':''.'>' . $term->name . '</option>';
                }                                   
            }
            ?>
    </select>
</label>
<label>
    Location
    <input type="text" name="job-location" class="search_job_location" placeholder="e.g. Manchester" value="<?php echo isset($_POST["job-location"])?esc_attr($_POST["job-location"]):'';?>">
</label>
<label>
    <input type="submit" class="search_submit" value="Search">
    <!-- <input type="hidden" name="post_type" value="jobs-board"> -->
</label>
</form>
```

Comment: That took me to the right page I listed but the page itself just said it couldn't be find (like a 404 error)?

Comment: It can be because of the field names. "s" is WordPress default search field name, and it makes a conflict with your code. Try using custom names:  First rename name="s" to name="ss" for example. If it doesn't help do the same with another form elements.

Comment: It's now going through that page but no results even though I put one in I knew for sure, also noticed the select field doesn't have any drop downs now either?

Comment: But your question was not about 404. The problem was " that page don't remember what was selected.". How did it appear then? My given code can't affect anything. So 404 is not about this question's topic

Comment: I know it wasn't, however when I used the code you provided instead of going to the page and showing the results like it did, it went to the same page and provided a 404 error instead.

Comment: can i see live URL?

Comment: The only addition by me is   echo '<option value="' . $term->name . '" part. replace it with  echo '<option and test it again